# Dismissing a ViewController and starting another in iOS (not a duplicate, other answers don't work)

Tags: android, ios, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have an Android app that I am trying to recreate for iOS using Xcode and Swift. It starts out with an animated screen that checks a few things then calls `finish()` and opens a login screen that I call `finish()` on too to start the main activity of the app. Sometimes I close the main activity with `finish()` and open the login screen again. I can't figure out how to do this in Swift.

When I try to dismiss the view controller in Swift after presenting the new one, it closes the new one instead of the old one. Rearranging these lines doesn't work either.

I've also tried to have a completion method that dismisses the current view controller after presenting the new one, and a completion method that presents a new one after dismissing the old one. Neither option works. Here is an example:

Dismissal of View Controller:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: present)
```

present() method:

```
    func present() {
    let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I want to have separate ViewControllers that don't depend on each other so I don't have a bunch of them stacked up endlessly.

Comment: present the new one without dismissing the old one. When you want to go back to the old one. Dismiss the new one.

Comment: Yes but take this for example:
If the user has no account:
Start -> Login -> (not registered) Register -> Verify Registration -> Main View Controller
If the user has an account:
Start -> Login -> Main View Controller

If the user has to login again, do I not have to make the app go back through all of the view controllers until it reaches login?

Comment: if you want to go forward - present. if you want to go backward - dismiss. I don't understand the issue here...

Comment: The issue is that I want to start new view controllers without adding endless view controllers to the stack of view controllers. How do I do that without writing a huge amount of unwind segues to get me to the start and sending a message down the line to present the view controller I want to present? In Android it takes literally two lines of code: startActivity(...) and finish()

Comment: if you keep presenting the same view controller, it doesn't add to the stack of controllers, it just presents the one that already exists

Answer (score 0):

You can only dismiss to an existing view controller in the navigation stack.
Try to dismiss to an existing view controller and then present the VC you want